# Is there person without consciousness?

Tags: karma, rebirth, anatman, pratityasamutpada, aggregates

If we consider person(Arthma) as a consciousness. When undergoing an operation, we are temporarily unconscious. Then what happens to that person while unconscious?

Some related discussion are here:

[I want to understand the technicality of rebirth and what happens to conditioned self](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/7810/i-want-to-understand-the-technicality-of-rebirth-and-what-happens-to-conditioned?rq=1).
[If there is no soul, how can there be rebirth?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/26/if-there-is-no-soul-how-can-there-be-rebirth).
[Is rebirth a delusional belief?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/is-rebirth-a-delusional-belief).
[What are examples of identity-view?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5862/what-are-examples-of-identity-view)

1. If we say these things are temporary illusions then how it is continued?
2. What are the similes use to explain this phenomena in any tradition?

Comment: It would be good when Nyom Bonn would give a useful answer here. **What's the matter with consciousness and how could person and knowing actually disappear?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing happens to that person when consciousness ceases - there was never a person to begin with, only arising and ceasing of experience.

I realized after the fact that I can't sufficiently cite sources while on my phone - apologies for such an incomplete answer, I'll try and expand later :)